# State or context error, when using multiprocessing with flask

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing.Process() to call a function big_task() whenever a request is received so that the function(which takes time to get computed) can run in my computer, while flask can run parallelly and listen for requests. But I am getting an error:

```
RuntimeError: No root path can be found for the provided module "__mp_main__".  This can happen because the module came from an import hook that does not provide file name information or because it's a namespace package.  In this case, the root path needs to be explicitly provided.
```

Based on another SO answer I tried giving the root_path argument when calling app=Flask(**name**,root_path:"C:/Users/..");

Now I get another error:

```
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'
```

This is my roughly my current code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
def big_task(arr):
     #some data manipulations using numpy
app=Flask(__name__,root_path="C:/Users/.../app")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
       k=request.form['arr']
       p=multiprocessing.Process(target=big_task,args=k)
       p.start()
       return 'ok'
if __name__=="__main__":
      app.run(debug=False)
```

I am new to flask, and don't quite understand why is this error happening. I think it is something related to flask creating its states or contexts, or something related to windows not being able to fork new process. Could someone give a good explanation ?